# AIR - NativeProcess With Sytem Profiler On Mac

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm attempting to use Adobe AIR NativeProcess in a Flex application to generate an XML file that I can parse to get various system information on a Mac (I have the equivalent working on Windows and I'm not very familiar with the Mac). I need information mostly about the CPU.

I'm unable to call the system profiler and pass the proper parameters (or any parameters) to get the NativeProcess to execute properly.

If I set the NativeProcess executable to:

/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/System Profiler

it executes, but I see the results popup on screen (it ignores my arguments to save it to a file which I believe makes sense since it is the GUI version).

If I set the NativeProcess executable to:

user/sbin/system_profiler or just system_profiler

nothing executes and I receive an ArgumentError #2004 on the line where I assign the executable.

The parameters are something like this:

systemDataMac.npArgList = ["-xml",">", systemDataFileName,"-detailLevel","basic"];

How can I get this file generated properly (or is there any other way to get the CPU information directly into my Flex/AIR app?

Thank you!

Sample Code:

```
        var nativeProcess:NativeProcess=new NativeProcess();
        var startupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo=new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var npArgs:Array = [];
        var appDataDir:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
        var nativeFilePath:String = appDataDir.nativePath.toString();

        nativeFilePath+= File.separator + "systemInfoFile.xml";

        nativeProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_IO_ERROR, onInputIOError); 
        nativeProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onOutputIOError);

        try
        {
            // tried each of these three
            startupInfo.executable=new File("system_profiler"); // throws error
            startupInfo.executable=new File("/user/sbin/system_profiler"); // throws error
            startupInfo.executable=new File("/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/System Profiler"); // works but doesn't handle args because it is the GUI version I believe

            npArgs = ["-xml",">", nativeFilePath,"-detailLevel","basic"];

            var args:Vector.<String>=new Vector.<String>();
            for each(var item:String in npArgs)
            {
                args.push(item);
            }

            startupInfo.arguments=args;

            nativeProcess.start(startupInfo);

        }
        catch (error:IllegalOperationError)
        {
            trace("Illegal Operator Error - " + error.toString());
        }
        catch (error:ArgumentError)
        {
            trace("Arg Error - " + error.toString());
        }
        catch (error:Error)
        {
            trace("Error - " + error.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Show some code on how you're trying to run it.

Comment: This should be the equivalent code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of information do you need?  Have you had a look at the [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class?

Comment: I'm looking for the CPU description, speed, and number of cores. I'm using the Capabilities class for some other information, but it doesn't contain detailed CPU information that I'm aware of.